# Trying to get first 3 bytes out of IP address regex

Tags: python, regex, string, ip

I'm trying to use the `re` module in python to match a string with regex. What I'm trying to get is `192.168.1.` from an IP address (so missing the last byte).

I've tried out my regex in a regex editor and it seems to work. The variable `original_ip` contains `192.168.1.65` in it already, so that's where I'm trying to extract the first 3 bytes plus the `.` from.

What I'm trying to do is get those `192.168.1.` from `192.168.1.5` and have it return a string.

Code:

```
original_ip = subprocess.check_output("""ipconfig getifaddr en0""", shell=True)
    print original_ip
    #extract the xxx.xxx.xxx.number part from it. so the first 3 bytes
    most_of_ip = re.match("\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\b", original_ip).group(0)
    print most_of_ip
```

error codes:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "arpdetector.py", line 120, in <module>
    main()
  File "arpdetector.py", line 99, in main
    assign_new_address()
  File "arpdetector.py", line 87, in assign_new_address
    most_of_ip = re.match("\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\b",    original_ip).group(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Why not split and join?

Comment: If you're using Python 3.3 and above use the [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) library.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7 IIRC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are not rawing your regex string:

```
most_of_ip = re.match(r"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\b", original_ip).group(0)
                  #   ^
```

This makes `\b` act as a word boundary, instead of the character representation of backspace (`"\b"` means backspace and if you try to match the regex `\b` with the string `\b`, you get `\x08` as the matched string).

But it could be done simpler with split and join:

```
most_of_ip = ".".join(original_ip.split(".")[0:3])+"."
```